# Div unload after scroll. Is it possible?

Tags: html

I would understand if it is possible "to unload" the contents of a div after scrolling a page that hides the div itself.

That is, I have a div with a pretty animation heavy (on older computers) and I would like that appears (and therefore the browser becomes heavy) when the user is viewing;
then, immediately after the scroll of the page (and thus leaving the div "at the top" of the page) that div I would like "to unload" and make it disappear so as to make lighter the page.

Comment: People like moving around... would you want it to be empty or gone if someone came back up?

Comment: [This thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling) here does the exact opposite. Try on it!

Comment: @sErVerdevIL, if people will came back up i want to be like before. Retrigger div (is a slowly and heavy slideshow).

That link doesn't "unload" div, only "opacity to 0" it.